# DirectX 12 do not update the pixel color after some frames

Tags: directx, hlsl, direct3d, directx-12

When I try to implement TAA, I update the pixel color like this:

```cpp
float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target
{ 
    float2 currPos = pin.PosH.xy * gInvRenderTargetSize;
    float2 histPos = currPos + gVelocityBuffer.Sample(gsamPointClamp, currPos).xy;

    float4 currPixel = gCurrFrameMap.Sample(gsamPointClamp, currPos);
    float4 histPixel = gHistoryFrameMap.Sample(gsamPointClamp, histPos);
    
    if(gFirstFrame == 1)
    {
        return currPixel;
    }
    
    float4 taaPixel = 0.05 * currPixel + 0.95 * histPixel;
    return taaPixel;
}
```

But after some frames it just show the history pixel instead of the new pixel, making the render result dirty. How could I solve this?

**This is the render target picture**

[image]

**The history frame**

[image]

**The current frame**

[image]

**The render target frame, and we can see that the pixel color do not change here**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the 95% History/5% Current split, you should completely eliminate any ghosting artifacts after 20 frames.

Instead, you eventually end up returning just `histPixel` with no contribution from `currPixel`, which indicates that some amount of `histPixel` is ending up in `currPixel`.

I can't say for certain without a video, but I think **you are using the previous displayed frame for `gCurrFrameMap`**. This still allows a better quality image, but only 20 frames (with each frame contributing less and less) of improvement.

Also, Sample the four neighboring pixels and clamp `histPixel` with the min and max of `currPixel` and those four samples. It will eliminate ghosting artifacts without having to reset to `currPixel` at `gFirstFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days I finally found the solution T_T.
This problem is caused by the **low precision** of **DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM**, so the updated value and the previous value will have the same RGBA value. Now I changed it to **DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT** and it was solved properly.